# Condition excludes rows from query with LEFT JOIN

Tags: c#, mysql, join

I have a statement that I am trying to use to retrieve a complete list of employees, and then their holidays. I would like to keep the employees even if they do not have holidays. This is my statement so far;

```
SELECT emp.em_pplid, emp.em_name
FROM employs emp
LEFT JOIN people ppl ON emp.em_pplid = ppl.pp_id
LEFT JOIN empwork ew ON emp.em_pplid = ew.ew_pplid
WHERE emp.em_deptid = ?
AND ppl.pp_employee = ?
AND emp.em_type < ?
AND ew.ew_from > ?
ORDER BY emp.em_name"
```

It is the `AND ew.ew_from = ?` that removes the employees that do not have holidays stored in the `empwork` table. How can I keep all the people in the employees table that have the department ID I want even if they have no holidays in the `empwork` table?

Comment: that topic doesn't match your problem description. Sounds to me that the AND clause removes rows, not columns. Please correct it to avoid misunderstandings.

Answer (score 0):

Your `where` clause turns your `left join`s into `inner join`s. Put the conditions into the `on` clause of your joins.

```
SELECT emp.em_pplid, emp.em_name
FROM employs emp
LEFT JOIN people ppl ON emp.em_pplid = ppl.pp_id                        
LEFT JOIN empwork ew ON emp.em_pplid = ew.ew_pplid
                    AND ew.ew_from > ?
WHERE emp.em_deptid = ?
AND emp.em_type < ?
AND (ppl.pp_employee IS NULL OR ppl.pp_employee = ?)
ORDER BY emp.em_name
```

Comment: Thanks for such a fast reply. This is working OK, it's just that `ppl.pp_employee` is still returning even those that should not be returned. Could this be being overridden further down?

Comment: It is unclear in what way the data should be reduced exactly. Please add example data and expected output to your question.

Comment: I'm using `sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("pEmployee", true);` to remove all those where `ppl.pp_employee = false` but they are still in the DataSet.

Comment: I updated the answer. Not sure if this is what you want

Answer (score 0):

Conditions on the **right** table of a `LEFT JOIN` should be specified only inside the `ON` clause . When they aren't , the join automatically transfer into an `INNER JOIN` due to `NULL` comparison:

```
SELECT emp.em_pplid, emp.em_name
FROM employs emp
LEFT JOIN people ppl
 ON emp.em_pplid = ppl.pp_id AND ppl.pp_employee = ?
LEFT JOIN empwork ew 
 ON emp.em_pplid = ew.ew_pplid AND ew.ew_from > ?
WHERE emp.em_deptid = ?
AND emp.em_type < ?
ORDER BY emp.em_name"
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question well this may work:

```
SELECT emp.em_pplid, emp.em_name
FROM employs emp
LEFT JOIN people ppl ON emp.em_pplid = ppl.pp_id
LEFT JOIN empwork ew ON emp.em_pplid = ew.ew_pplid
WHERE emp.em_deptid = ?
AND ppl.pp_employee = ?
AND emp.em_type < ?
AND (ew.ew_from > ? OR ew.ew_from IS NULL)
ORDER BY emp.em_name"
```